# How to build a General Linear Model

Tags: r, glm

An Accountable Care Organization (ACO) has engaged us to assist in helping them develop a predictive modeling solution to reduce the prevalence of strokes in the population they manage. Their plan is to develop an outreach program where a team of health coaches will work with members to reduce their risk of stroke. However, they do not have enough resources to engage every member of their population. Therefore, they would like us to develop a model that can be used to match the health coaches with those individuals who have the highest risk of stroke. To solve this problem, we would like you to first build a generalized linear model (GLM). If time permits, we would then like you to try to build a more advanced model to compete with the benchmark performance of your GLM. We are interested to see both the difference in performance and your thoughts on any important advantages or disadvantages to either method.

[image]

build a GLM model with the above dataset

Comment: I am very concerned that an ACO has engaged individuals who don't know how to build a rudimentary GLM to identify at-risk individuals. Especially given results will be used to make care decisions. Thousands of peer-reviewed research papers identify the main predictors of stroke. You can look at your data and tell which individuals are most at-risk without a GLM. Especially given the size of your dataset. Importantly, LDL cholesterol and diabetes status aren't explicit in your data, unless they're represented in the metric columns that is (which is likely given the values).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you need a consultant, you will need to hire one. Hopefully, you won't fall into the same trap as your customer and get someone competent.